# Structure a default data object to be replicated with changes

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a game with 2 players. They have almost same beginning data and of course it changes in the course of the game.

I am guessing I need some king of constructor object that I will replicate and then modify, also I need it to be JSON for easy ajax sending.

Is there a design pattern that can help me? I prefer not to use database since I need the data only for a single game instance.

This is the structure I use now for one player:

```
player = {
    "active" : true,
    "room" : openRoom,
    "id" : playerID,
    "name": username,
    "hp" : 5,
    "units" : {
        1 : {
            "id" : 1,
            "hp" : 3,
            "row" : 1,
            "square" : 1
        },
        2 : {
            "id" : 2,
            "hp" : 4,
            "row" : 2,
            "square" : 1
        },
        3 : {
            "id" : 3,
            "hp" : 5,
            "row" : 3,
            "square" : 1
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "JSON"?

Comment: @Bergi He means [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html). Google is a great tool! :)

Comment: @Web_Designer: I know what JSON is and that the code he posted does not use it. So I wanted to know how his object literals are related to JSON.

Comment: It doesn't take much to convert his object to JSON: `JSON.stringify(player)` returns a JSON string.

Comment: @Bergi why is it not JSON? because of the variables?

Comment: also, I can't use jQuery because it is in node.js

Comment: @IlyaD: It's an object literal - a JavaScript syntax construct. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a file format, and if you use it in JS it's a string.

Comment: @Bergi I never heard that JSON is only a file format, as far as I understand it's a data structure. when I use Ajax to send JSON, I don't use a JSON file.

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. It is a lightweight data-interchange format (as per the very link @Bergi posted). It's not a file format per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several design patterns regarding object instantiation and initialization. However, you don't seem to need any inheritance or "property sharing" techniques, so a very simple function that returns a new object should fit well as a constructor. You even can use object literals in coding it.

An example of two constructor functions, each with some parameters:

```
function makePlayer(id, name, units) {
    return {
        "active" : true,
        "room" : openRoom,
        "id" : id,
        "name": name,
        "hp" : 5,
        "units" : units
    };
}
var uuid = 1;
function makeUnit(row) {
    return {
        "id" : uuid++,
        "hp" : 3,
        "row" : row,
        "square" : 1
    };
}
var player = makePlayer(playerId, username, [makeUnit(2), makeUnit(4), makeUnit(3)]);
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(player);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

In the "Using an object constructor" section is all the info you need, it shows an example using a Person object, but it is directly applicable to what you are trying to do I think.

Happy coding!

Comment: That's really [not the best reference](http://w3fools.com/) on objects. The section on methods is oversimplifying, and the section on constructor function does not mention prototypes at all.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi reading through this article some more, I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to clone JSON object. The easiest way using JQuery is

```
player1 = $.extend({}, player, {name:"Allen"});
player2 = $.extend({}, player, {name:"John"});
```

If you don't use JQuery, use JSON object

```
var player1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(player));
var player2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(player));
player1.name = "Allen";
player2.name = "John";
```